# how to send multiple document dynamically to whatsapp number using asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, selenium

I have one module which contain data in table(like: checkboxes, Office, month, year,PDF and Send button).
[See this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyAep.png).

I want to send multiple document via WhatsApp by checking with checkbox field, after click on send button in bottom left-corner of the form.

Then one popup will generate, and user will enter mobile no in TextBox of popup window and after clicking on submit button list of PDF will be send on given mobile number.

How to do this? or give any suggestion/link.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you tied anything so far ? can we see the code/approach u have tried ? We cannot provide you the entire code/solution for a problem. We can only help where u stuck

Comment: Note : Remove the link and include that image directly in the question

Comment: I cannot post the code due to some credential purpose.